# Xcode Quiz look-a-like app with question and answer

Tags: arrays, swift, random

I am trying to create a quiz look-a-like app, where the person who holds the phone ask the question, and the other people answer. So there will be two Strings. One with question, and one with the answer. I have created the questions something like this:

```
var questions = ["Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question4", "Question5"]
var answers = ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4", "Answer5"]
```

When the tap a button, a new question with correct answer pops up. I know how I can display a random string from questions, but how do I connect it to also display the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a `Dictionary`, with the Question as the `Key` and the Answer as the `Value`:

```
let questions: [String : String] = [
    "Question1" : "Answer1",
    "Question2" : "Answer2",
    "Question3" : "Answer3",
    "Question4" : "Answer4",
    "Question5" : "Answer5"
]
```

You can then get a random Question & Answer like this:

```
let randomQuestion = questions.randomElement()
```

Then access the Question and Answer Text:

```
let questionText = randomQuestion?.key ?? ""
let answerText = randomQuestion?.value ?? ""
```

---

In relation to your next question:
***How can I make sure the same question does not show multiple times, and when there are no more questions***

You can construct an `Array` from the `Dictionary` `Keys` like this.  The keys will be unordered anyway, but you should shuffle them if you want to repeat.
You can then iterate through each question in the randomised Array:

Set your properties in `viewDidLoad`, not when the button is tapped.

```
let randomQuestions = questions.keys.shuffled()
var currentQuestionIndex = 0

@IBAction func newQuestionButton(_ sender: Any) {
    guard currentQuestionIndex != questions.count else {
        return
        // or reset your questionIndex and reshuffle.
    }

    // This will give you the Question (and Key)
    let question = randomQuestions[currentQuestionIndex]

    // Use the Key to extract out the answer (value) from the Dictionary
    let answer = questions[question] ?? ""

    // Update your labels
    questionLabel.text = question
    answerLabel.text = answer

    // Increment your question index
    currentQuestionIndex += 1
}
```

Comment: Very nice! A question: How can I make sure the same question does not shows multiple times, and when there are no more questions, the questionLabel says: "No more questions"?

Comment: Did I do something wrong? Look here: https://pastebin.com/VuMPxT5S - It shows the same question and answer multiple time, and does not stop when all questions is shown.

Comment: Thats because you are running the whole loop every time the button is pressed.  I just showed it in a loop as an example.  You would have to have a variable for current question starting at 0, and then incremented every time the new Question button is tapped, ensuring that you do not exceed the count of the question bank.

Comment: Oh, so I am not supposed to use a loop for this? Isn't loop the best option?

Comment: I've updated my answer for you, but this is getting well beyond the scope of your question, which I've answered.

Comment: Well, at least you helped a brother in need :) Thank you mate!

Comment: Is it possible to use 3 answers? `var questions: [String : String : String] = [`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `zip` together `questions` and `answers` and then call `randomElement` on the result. This will give you a `Tuple` containing a random question and its respective answer - assuming the indices of `questions` and `answers` are in sync.

```
var questions = ["Question1", "Question2", "Question3", "Question4", "Question5"]
var answers = ["Answer1", "Answer2", "Answer3", "Answer4", "Answer5"]
let questionsAndAnswers = Array(zip(questions, answers))

let randomQA = questionsAndAnswers.randomElement()
```

Comment: Nice! But how do I add the question to the questionLabel, and answer to the answerLabel from the `Tuple`?

Comment: @Conrooo just do `questionLabel.text = randomQA?.0` and `answerLabel.text = randomQA?.1`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `QuizItem` type like. Since you always need them together it is good practice to tie them together in one element instead of having two arrays.

```swift
struct QuizItem {
  var question: String
  var answer: String
}
```

Then you create and array (or list) `[QuizItem]` and add all items you want. At last you simply take random element of the array.
Here is some pseudo code:

```swift
var quizList = [QuizItem]()
quizList.append(...) // add questions & answers

let randomIndex = randomIndex between 0 and quizList.length-1
let item = quizList[randomIndex]

questionLable.text = item.question
answereLabel.text = item.answere
```